# How does polling SCM in jenkins work? - in depth

Tags: multithreading, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, polling

I have a question that how does the "polling SCM in jenkins work"? I am seeking an explanation in terms of how it creates a thread or a process (if it does) to poll, while continuously polling let's say (every 5 minutes). Does polling create only a new thread in an existing process or does it create new processes? What it does to these created processes/threads once the polling returns the change or no change?
I am suspecting, too much polling is keeping my jenkins server busy and having performance issues. However, I could not find proper documentation or discussion that explains this process. I would like be educated on this.

Comment: i'm curious about the answer to your question from an academic perspective, but wouldn't use polling because i can use pushing and pushing is way better. canonical article from Kohsuke: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-git-hook. any chance you could use webhooks to push?

Comment: Yes, I am looking forward to use webhooks to push. But I wanted to investigate on the root cause of the problem. Also, I am curious to know how jenkins polling work in terms of process and threads. Not finding helpful document on that though.